# WiFi cycle with hostapd

Tags: wifi, network-interface, hostapd

I'm using hostapd to broadcast my wireless network. I'm cycling through a list of config files. I'm able to create a wireless network the first time, but as soon as I'm trying to cycle to the next one it gives the following errors:

```
root@RaspberryPi:~# hostapd -B /tmp/hostapd.conf
Configuration file: /tmp/hostapd.conf
Failed to update rate sets in kernel module
Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr 4e:53:50:4f:4f:4e and ssid 'WiFi'
ctrl_iface exists and seems to be in use - cannot override it
Delete 'wlan0/wlan0' manually if it is not used anymore
Failed to setup control interface
wlan0: Unable to setup interface.
```

Here is where the broadcasting stops. I always get the kernel module error, but it works the first time without a problem. So it must be the other part. Unfortunately I don't understand the error `ctrl_iface exists and seems to be in use - cannot override it` and what comes after it. I have a hard time searching for the answer, so hopefully you people can help me out. How do I succesfully cycle through the list of config files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The only thing required for it to work is to execute the following command before the next hostapd command is given:

```
pkill -15 hostapd
```